# div:hover works but moves the div to the right of it

Tags: html, css

I'm making navigation for my site and I'm using divs and the `:hover` property combined with images for my drop-down menus.

```css
#top .main-menu-container {
    position: relative;
}
#top .main-menu {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: none; 
    z-index: 98;
}
#top .main-menu li {
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 15px;
}
#top .main-menu  img{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#top .main-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
.sub-menu {
    background-color: #fafafa; 
    padding: 10px; 
    margin: -4px auto 0px auto; 
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px -2px #444;
    display: none; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    width: 200px; 
    z-index: 99; 
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #666; 
    border-top-left-radius: 7px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px; 
}
```

My CSS consists of this in case anyone can see any immediate errors.

My problem being that when you hover over the image, it displays the sub-menu div but it also moves the other buttons across the page equal to the width of the sub-menu div.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DU3Gm/) demo.

Comment: It's because you have the link button and the sub-menu dropdown in the same LI.

Comment: Im not quite sure how to interpret that. What are you implying that i do?

Comment: Move the sub-menu div outside of the LI that has the menu button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the div that is within the list is pushing the content to the right.

A quick way around this is to throw a `position: relative;` on the parent element and a `position: absolute;` on the child element (div) that is pushing the surrounding elements.

[Here's a link to a jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/DU3Gm/1/)

More specifics:

```
#top .main-menu li {
 position: relative;
}
```

The following tells the sub-menu to position itself to the absolute left: 0 position relative to the parent element

```
.sub-menu {
 //existing code
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I see how this fixed it and I have learned from this

Comment: Glad! Relative and Absolute positioning can be tricky if you don't quite understand how they work in relation to the parent!

Comment: I still need to learn about it a little more. Gonna have a scout around

Answer (score 0):

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DU3Gm/3/)

```
#top .main-menu li {
float: left; margin-right: 15px;
position:relative;
}
.sub-menu {
background-color: #fafafa;
padding: 10px; margin: -4px auto 0px auto; box-shadow: 0 5px 20px -2px #444;
display: none; 
left: 0; right: 0; width: 200px; z-index: 99; text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #666; border-top-left-radius: 7px; border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
position:absolute;   
}
```